# How to implement trusted places in my Android application

Tags: android, unlock

Looking in all the usual places and google, but I am unable to find any "developer" level information on implementing "trusted places" in my application. At this point I'm considering that Google, may be keeping this information private or proprietary. Does anyone out there know differently and want to share an example or point me in the right direction?

tl;dr I want to use "Trusted Places" in my personally developed Android apps.

**EDIT**

I plan to implement my own trusted places in pre 5.0 builds; for 5+ I want to use an API to access the trusted places related to smart lock.

Related links:

[Set up automatic unlock](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6093922?hl=en)

[On-body detection](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/03/20/trusted-butts-new-on-body-detection-smart-lock-mode-in-android-seems-to-be-hitting-some-devices/)

[Trusted places use Geo-fencing](http://www.techspot.com/news/58888-android-lollipop-trusted-places-uses-geo-fencing-unlock.html)

**EDIT 2**

Found this post about non-public API [Dissecting Lollipop's Smart Lock](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2014/12/dissecting-lollipops-smart-lock.html)

Comment: If you are asking how to find out what the user told Settings/Smart Lock was a "trusted place", I am not aware of an API for that. However, you can collect your own locations from the user and consider them to be "trusted" for the scope of your own app. You would need to do that for pre-Android 5.0 anyway, even if there were an API for finding the Smart Lock "trusted places".

Comment: Good questions, I'm glad you noticed my question @CommonsWare being that you are an Android expert.